# Multiple one-to-many matching between vectors in R

Tags: r

I want to update a dataframe with values from a table of new values where there is a one-to-many relationship between the dataframe and table of new values. This code illustrates the intent:

```
df = data.frame(x=rep(letters[1:4],5,rep=T), y=1:20)
```

and new values..

```
eds = data.frame(x=c('c','d'), val=c(101, 102))
```

For a one-to-one relationship the following should work:

```
df$x[match(eds$x, df$x)] = eds$x[match(df$x, eds$x)]
```

But match only works with first match, so this throws the error `number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`.  Grateful for any tips on the most efficient way to approach this.  I'm guessing some `sapply` wrapper but I can't think of the method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think it is a programming problem, you need an aggregation operation to bring the one-to-many problem back to a one-to-one problem. Or do you want to replicate values? In the latter case you should try a `merge`.

Comment: Hi asb. I just want to update the 'y' values of relevant rows in `df` with their matching corresponding 'y' values in `eds`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tmp  <- eds$val[match(df$x, eds$x)]   # Matching indices (with NAs for no match)
df$y <- ifelse(is.na(tmp), df$y, tmp) # Values at matches (leaving alone for NAs)

head(df, 5)
#   x   y
# 1 a   1
# 2 b   2
# 3 c 101
# 4 d 102
# 5 a   5
```

Answer (score 1):

Not that this not a very robust solution. It depends on your exact data structure here (repeating 'c', 'd' pattern) but it works for this case:

```
df[df[["x"]] %in% eds[["x"]], "y"] = eds[[2]]
```

Comment: Hmm this works but I can't see how! `df[["x"]] %in% eds[["x"]]` (or for that matter `df$x %in% eds$x`) just returns logical vector not the match positions..

Comment: It is an ill-advised use of `logical subsetting` and `vector recycling` in R.

Comment: Ah I see I'll have to read into vector recycling! Guess I should give the answer to Josh's less elegant but more advisable method, but thanks.